# Copy sheet without copying buttons

Tags: vba, excel

i am trying to make a character creator tool for a game.
im almost done but i wanted to add a button the saves the character
code looking like this

```
Sub Save_character()
Dim ws As Worksheet

Worksheets("character creator").Copy _
After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("character creator")

Set ws = ActiveSheet

ws.Name = Range("b14")

End Sub
```

but i dont want this button to be added to the copied sheet.
Any idea how i may do that?

thx in advence.
a VBA/excel rookie

Comment: What button? I'm sort of confused - why not use `Worksheets("character creator").Range("B14")`?  You set `ws` as the ActiveSheet, being the copied sheet. I recommend instead, at the very start, to declare your activesheet as `ws`, then after you copy `ws`, name it `wsCopy` or such.

Comment: OH - Or are you saying that `Worksheets("Character creator")` has a button on it, and when you copy the sheet, you want to remove the button that's on there?

Comment: Batman, pretty sure it's latter. What I don't get is why OP can't delete after paste XD

Comment: If it's my second comment, then on your `ws` (again, I suggest calling this like `copyWS`, but that's just a personal suggestion), why not loop through the buttons and delete them all (or just loop for the one you want to delete)?  Alternatively, how large is that `Character Creator` sheet? If it's just a few values (under say 1000), you could create a new sheet, and just put the values on there by setting two ranges equal. No copy/paste needed!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's a setting for this:

```
Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = False
'copy your sheet
Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = True 'reset
```

Same as:
 *Options >> Advanced >> Cut, Copy and Sort inserted objects with their parent cells* (uncheck)

Answer (score 3):

You can delete the button using

`ws.Shapes("YourButtonName").Delete`

Answer (score 0):

Do what Scott recommended, or do what you are doing now, and delete the button object after you have copied the sheet.  Something like this should do it for you . . .

```
ActiveSheet.Objects.Delete
```